# Use single WKWebView in all UIViewControllers in UITabbarController iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, wkwebview

I am working on UITabbarViewController application where I have 5 tabs. On Each tab, I have to show WKWebView with some URL. Now my problem is, If I perform any action on WKWebView in first tab then it should highlight or select the second tab with the updated URL. In short, how we can use same WKWebView with each and every tab.

Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `UITabbarController` can't do this, since all the tabs have their own view hierarchy. I would suggest making your own `UIControl` that allows users to select "tabs".

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for your reply :) I wanted to make sure if we can share same instance on all viewControllers .

Answer (score 0):

Have a look through [the VisitableView class in Turbo iOS](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-ios/blob/dcab2693a3c0f2b3aa3227ca5b62aaac215771bf/Source/Visitable/VisitableView.swift#L139).

When you tap on a link, it replaces the web view with a snapshot and puts it in a new view controller. It is moving the web view onto each new view controller as it is pushed onto a navigation stack.